# size of bipole twoport?

Tags: circuitikz

I am quite new to TikZ/CircuiTikZ so my question may sound stupid. Anyway, I want to create this figure, but I cannot figure out how to make the bipole twoport fit the label inside itself. Any suggestion?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw (0,0) node[adder](sum) {};
    \draw (sum.east) to[twoport,>, t=$G_{loop}(s)$] ++(2,0) node[right]{$y$}
    -- ++(0,-1) -| (sum.south)
    node[inputarrow, rotate=90]{};
    \draw (-.5,0) to node[at start, left]{$x$} (sum.west) node[inputarrow]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please include the styles for `adder`, `twoport`, etc. Basically, make your MWE compilable (it's not currently).

Comment: @Alenanno I edited, I forgot to add one line from the preamble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the chapter **7.2 Components size** in the [Circuitikz manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf) (currently page 49), you can use the key `bipoles/length` to change the dimensions of components. You can assign this to a particular style, so then you can use it in components.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{
    mylength/.style={bipoles/length=#1}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw (0,0) node[adder](sum) {};
    \draw (sum.east) to[twoport,>, t=$G_{loop}(s)$, mylength=2cm] ++(2,0) node[right]{$y$}
        -- ++(0,-1) -| (sum.south)
        node[inputarrow, rotate=90]{};
    \draw (-.5,0) to node[at start, left]{$x$} (sum.west) node[inputarrow]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of this solution! I would have liked to keep the same height for the block, but maybe in this case it's more convenient to define my own node..